# How to transform a azure blob storage in a virtual disk driver

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Hello i am actually working on Azure services and i want to know if it's possible to work with a azure blob storage as a virtual machine hard drive? If possible can we by the inclusion of the virtual machine include the blob storage in a VNet?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add storage as a network resource but you can add a new virtual disk backed by your blob storage. This link has more details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-attach-disk-portal?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json

Answer (score 0):

> if it's possible to work with a azure blob storage as a virtual
>   machine hard drive?

Do you mean mount azure blob storage on Azure VM? If is, the answer is no. You could not mount blob storage to a VM. You could download/upload blob data to your VMs . **You also could mount Azure File Shares to VMs. Azure File share supports SMB.** When you mount Azure File shares on your VMs, you could use them like as hard drives.